# In terms of sys module dictionary, what happens when importing by using - package vs module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

In terms of sys module dictionary, writing `import modulename` or `from modulename import function/variable` loads entire module into the sys modules dictionary table.

Does import package also behave in same way. That is - when using `import package` or `from package import modulename`; does this load all modules from the package into the sys modules dictionary table?

Comment: Cache table is the table into which the module is loaded.

Comment: Do you mean [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules)? If so, you can always print its contents and see what effect different operations have.

Comment: Yes. Symbol table

Comment: It's not a symbol table per se, it's a dictionary used as a cache of modules which have been `import`ed.

Answer (score 0):

> sys.modules mapping serves as a cache of all modules that have been
>   previously imported, including the intermediate paths. So if
>   foo.bar.baz was previously imported, sys.modules will contain entries
>   for foo, foo.bar, and foo.bar.baz. Each key will have as its value the
>   corresponding module object.

When any python package is imported then its `__init__.py` file is implicitly executed and extra bindings are added into the `sys.modules` because of this.

Like if you import python `requests` package then the following entries are added to the `sys.modules`

```
requests
requests.exceptions
requests.__version__
requests.utils
requests.certs
requests._internal_utils
requests.compat
requests.cookies
requests.structures
requests.models
requests.hooks
requests.auth
requests.status_codes
requests.api
requests.sessions
requests.adapters
```